# Composer tilde syntax (Next significant release)

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I've installed [amnah/yii2-user](https://packagist.org/packages/amnah/yii2-user) library from [packagist](https://packagist.org) via [composer](https://getcomposer.org) into my project. The project's `composer.json` relevant require section looks like:

"amnah/yii2-user": "~2.0"

To my understanding, this should install the latest version with a major version of "2". When I check the installed package via `composer show amnah/yii2-user -v`, I see the following version information:

> ```
> versions : dev-master, 2.1.0-alpha4, 2.1.0-alpha3, 2.1.0-alpha2, 2.1.0alpha,
> ```
>
> * 2.0.0-alpha2, 2.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-beta

So `2.0.0-alpha2` is installed, the `2.1` versions are ignored. Isn't it supposed to work like

> Another way of looking at it is that using ~ specifies a minimum
>   version, but allows the last digit specified to go up.

as the documentation states? I'd need the latest 2.x version installed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the latest 2.x version installed, you should use `~2.1` if "latest" means that at that time a version 2.1 is the most current version released.

But I wonder why you are getting the alpha version installed. Usually Composer defaults to only install stable versions, no release candidates (rc), beta, alpha nor dev versions. Did you add a setting for `minimum-stability` and/or `preferred-stability`?

So if you want alpha versions, you should require `~2.1@alpha`.

And a word of caution: The project you are using does require `yiisoft/yii2: *` and `yiisoft/yii2-authclient: *` - asterisk meaning that ANY version is sufficient. Yii itself claims that the released 1.1 version is incompatible with the newer 2.0 series (which is not yet released), whatever that means.

Comment: Thanks! I do added "minimum-stability": "dev" to the config. I'm intentionally using yii2 which is currently in strong beta phase.